# python Selenium PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to open up a Internet Explorer with python Selenium but keep getting an error "**PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied**".

I have downloaded Internet Explorer Driver Server ran the script as administrator is there anything else I could do?

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie(r"C:\\Users\\N\\Downloads\\IEwebdriver\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1")
driver.get("http://www.hotmail.com")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

The full error message

```
C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/N/PycharmProjects/first/SeleniumScripts/Myfirstscripts.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/N/PycharmProjects/first/SeleniumScripts/Myfirstscripts.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Ie(r"C:\\Users\\N\\Downloads\\IEwebdriver\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1")
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.iedriver.start()
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1' executable may have wrong permissions. Please download from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.ie.service.Service object at 0x01C9D410>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using Microsoft Windows 10.

Comment: well, the error says "IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1' executable may have wrong permissions. Please download from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver".  Did you do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The driver wasn't pointing at the exe file! so it should of been.

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(r"C:\\Users\\N\\Downloads\\IEwebdriver\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are not going to set up the environmental variable PATH, you should point it directly to the .exe file rather than the subfolder

```
driver=webdriver.Ie(r"C:\\Users\\N\\Downloads\\IEwebdriver\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the driver for your chrome version, and place it on your chrome path.

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads