# Can't start Tor with Python, Selenium: Tor failed to start

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The program should open Tor with selenium, but when i start it, it has an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Seya Fässler/Desktop/Python/test4.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=r'C:/Users/Seya Fässler/Webdrivers/geckodriver.exe')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Zugriff verweigert (os error 5)


(base) C:\Users\Seya Fässler\Desktop\Python>C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/Seya Fässler/Desktop/Python/test4.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Seya Fässler/Desktop/Python/test4.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=r'C:/Users/Seya Fässler/Webdrivers/geckodriver.exe')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__        
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Access Denied (os error 5)
```

The program starts Tor but it says: Tor failed to start.
I use Windows 10 with Python 3.8.3. And sorry for this Newbie question, i am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: As an aside, using the base environment for development is a bad idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python Selenium PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959885/python-selenium-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied)

Comment: Normally i use anaconda as an environment

Comment: No, i have geckodriver.exe at the end

Comment: _No, i have geckodriver.exe at the end_ Are you certain the path is correct, though?

Comment: Yes, im 100% sure